# How do you solve FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fixtures

When running my tests I get this error:

```
FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find
```

What causes this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most likely this happens because a custom table name is used for a Model (using the set_table_name) or the model is in a module.

To solve, you need to add a `set_fixture_class` line in the `test_helper.rb` before the `fixtures :all` line:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  .
  .
  .
  set_fixture_class my_table_name: MyModule::MyClass

  fixtures :all

end
```

In this case the fixtures file should be called my_table_name.yml

Comment: If your class is not in a module (your answer isn't 100% clear on this) it might be due to a weird model name that Rails' inflector doesn't know how to singularize correctly. In that case you would be better off adding a custom inflection in config/initializers/inflections.rb, as it's likely to cause problems in other areas as well.

Comment: i was facing same error after adding this line my error is changed to  ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: comparison of String with Class failed

Comment: @wasipeer: try `set_fixture_class my_table_name: MyModule::MyClass`

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: It would be helpful if you included the stack trace and the full error message.

In your test/test_helper.rb class, there is a line like

```
fixtures :all
```

This tells the framework to look in the directory test/fixtures and try to load each of the YAML files that it sees there and then save them to the DB.  So my hunch is that you have a file in there that does not have class in app/models with the singularized name.  In other words, if there is a file test/fixtures/posts.yml, then when you run your tests, the framework will look for a class named Post to load your data in.

So the first thing I would do is check to see if you have a fixture file that is not associated with one of your model classes (maybe you deleted a model but forgot to delete the fixture?)

If that doesn't work, try changing the line in your test helper to explicitly load the fixtures you need.  So if you only want to load fixtures for an object named Post and an object named User, you will change:

```
fixtures :all
```

to

```
fixtures :posts, :users
```

in test_helper.rb and you should see the error go away (although other errors may now appear because your fixtures are not loaded.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob. I actually found the solution and added it as an answer here.

Comment: Note that if you have "fixtures :all" in many unit test files, you have to put the set_fixture_class in each file as well, not just in the places were you are going to use fixtures from that model. This really confused me, but it does make sense after coffee. I would rather that somehow this info was DRY into the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the Event that the Class is an irregular class in terms of naming such as `fish`, `sms`
it could have been created by using the `--force-plural` flag
i.e
`rails g model sms --force-plural`

in that case you would set up an inflection which is set up under 
`config/initializers/inflections.rb`

an example of such is this

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
  inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
  inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
  inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
end
```

In this way the class can be recognized as you declared it

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I made a mistake generating some scaffold code. I used a plural model name, and that just confused the fixture loading, I guess. Regenerating the scaffold with a singular model name fixed the problem.