# Fixture Class Not found error on simple rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am trying to set up the rails testing framework but am facing some issues. My setup is as follows

test/models/clinic_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClinicTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "sample" do
    clinic = clinics(:myclinic)
    assert(clinic.name == 'Krishan')
  end
end
```

test/fixtures/clinics.yml

```
myclinic:
  name: Krishan
```

But when I run the clinic_test rake process I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find
   test/models/clinic_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ClinicTest>'
```

I see that the database is actually populated with the sample data from the clinics.yml file.

Where is the problem? Is this some configuration issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you solve FixtureClassNotFound: No class attached to find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020494/how-do-you-solve-fixtureclassnotfound-no-class-attached-to-find)

Answer (score 7):

Add following lines in test_helper.rb file, before **fixtures :all**

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  set_fixture_class clinics: Clinic
  fixtures :all
  ...
end
```

**clinics** is the name of yml file where **Clinic** is the name of model.

Comment: Can you or someone tell us more about why we need to do that ? I never saw that in fixture documentation or other code samples. I have the same issue with a simple generated straightforward model.

Comment: you can find it here https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods/set_fixture_class @SimontheSalmon

Comment: Ok it is for "when the class name cannot be inferred from the fixture name", I had the problem with french class names (the plural of adress is the same between french and english but not the singular, I spent quite a while figuring that out)